# Java Jena - SPARQL Update query to remote endpoint

Tags: sparql, jena

How can I use Jena to run SPARQL update queries to a remote endpoint? (assuming I am allowed to).

So far, what I have is the following

```java
UpdateRequest update = UpdateFactory.create(queryString);
UpdateProcessor processor = UpdateExecutionFactory.create(update, dataset);
processor.execute();
```

But I do not know what `dataset` is and where to add the remote endpoint URL.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK, so here is the solution:

```java
RDFConnection conn = RDFConnectionFactory.connect(endpoint);
UpdateRequest update = UpdateFactory.create(queryString);
conn.update(update);
```

Comment: Yes - that will work - as will `UpdateExec.service(endpoint).update(updateString).execute()` which is what RDFConnection does.